# configuring gps module ssf1513

Tags: embedded, gps

hi i am developing code for gps tracker using gps module ssf1513. i don't know  how to  configure the  gps module to power save mode , please guide me how  to enter in  input mode.

Answer (score 3):

That board has a SiRF starIII GSC3e/LPx GPS chip.

You can Communicate with it via SiRF's binary protocol or NMEA here are links to the reference manuals for each:

[SiRF NMEA Reference Manual](http://www.usglobalsat.com/downloads/NMEA_commands.pdf)

[SiRF Binary Reference Manual](http://www.navmanwirelessoem.com/158.html)

How exactly you want to save power is up to you there are tons of ways to reduce power usage with gps (duty cycle control, long sleeps, etc).  This will be application dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It my be that the power save mode is automatic, e.g. if you stop polling the device then it may go into power saving mode after a certain time-out, and then wake up again automatically when you start polling it again ?